# cppcheck How to suppress inline unmatched suppression?

Tags: c++, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

**I found that `--suppress=unmatchedSuppression` only suppresses unmatched suppression types in cppcheck options, but NOT unmatched inline suppressions.**

Is this the expected behavior?

> **test.c**

- Line 4 is wrong. It should be warned `arrayIndexOutOfBounds`
- Line 7 is okay. It should NOT be warned `arrayIndexOutOfBounds`

I have inline `cppcheck-suppress` for both lines.

```
  1 void f() {
  2     char arr[5];
  3     // cppcheck-suppress arrayIndexOutOfBounds
  4     arr[10] = 0;
  5
  6     // cppcheck-suppress arrayIndexOutOfBounds
  7     const char ok[] = "this line is ok";
  8 }
```

> **Situation 1**

Suppress `cstyleCast`, which does NOT exist in code.

```
 cppcheck --inline-suppr --force --enable=all 
          --xml-version=2 --suppress=cstyleCast test.c 
          2>cppcheckresults.xml
```

I get warned about (among other irrelevant warnings)

1. `unmatchedSuppression: arrayIndexOutOfBounds` in `test.c` `line 7` (as expected)
2. `unmatchedSuppression: cstyleCast` in `*` `line 0` (as expected)

> **Situation 2**

Same as situation 1, but with additional `--suppress=unmatchedSuppression` option

```
 cppcheck --inline-suppr --force --enable=all 
          --xml-version=2 --suppress=cstyleCast --suppress=unmatchedSuppressiontest.c 
          2>cppcheckresults.xml
```

**I expect both previous `unmatchedSuppression` warnings to go away. But I still get**

1. `unmatchedSuppression` in `test.c` `line 7` (NOT expected)

Comment: Do you have a typo in the last code block? should say "`unmatchedSuppression:test.c`" instead of "`unmatchedSuppressiontest.c`"?

Comment: This problem is still present in cppcheck 2.3. I found a workaround, see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I recently found is that an `unmatchedSuppression` warning from inline suppressions cannot be suppressed by a generic `--suppress=unmatchedSuppression` or putting just that warning ID in a `--suppressions-list` file. You have to qualify it with the filename. For example `--suppress=unmatchedSuppression:test.c`.

Comment: You can say `--suppress=unmatchedSuppression:{}`, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the order solution is that you have to do this for every file that has the unmatched suppression.

A. In the command line use the option `--suppress=unmatchedSuppression:{}`. (note the curly braces)

B. What I discovered is that you can also suppress the unmatched suppression itself in place, for example:

```
        // cppcheck-suppress[assertWithSideEffect,unmatchedSuppression]
        assert(...);
```

(tested with cppcheck 2.3 and 2.5)

This is necessary for example when running cppcheck 2.3 which didn't have the `assertWithSideEffect` feature, later availabe in cppcheck 2.5.

Ideally, as you bump the cppcheck version you can start removing the unnecessary `unmatchedSuppression`.
Needless to say, this all needs the command line `--inline-suppr`.